# SQLite on Android: Different result set at Runtime vs. SQLite Administrator

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am building an Android app with an internal SQLite DB.
Here is the schema:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tblImageVideoLink] (
[LinkID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[ImageID] INTEGER  UNIQUE NOT NULL,
[VideoID] INTEGER  NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tblImages] (
[ID] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[ImageName] VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL,
[ImageDescription] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
[Page] INTEGER  NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tblPages] (
[ID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[PageName] VARCHAR(30)  NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS [tblVideos] (
[ID] INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
[VideoName] VARCHAR(150)  NOT NULL,
[VideoDescription] VARCHAR(100)  NULL,
[VideoType] VARCHAR(10)  NULL
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS [IDX_TBLIMAGEVIDEOLINK_IMAGEID] ON [tblImageVideoLink](
[ImageID]  DESC,
[VideoID]  DESC
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS [IDX_TBLIMAGES_PAGE] ON [tblImages](
[Page]  DESC
);
```

Here's the relevant data I have in the tables:

```
INSERT INTO tblImages (ID, ImageName, Page) VALUES (1, 'Beach.jpg', 1);
INSERT INTO tblImages (ID, ImageName, Page) VALUES (2, 'Bowling.jpg', 1);
INSERT INTO tblImages (ID, ImageName, Page) VALUES (3, 'Car.jpg', 1);
INSERT INTO tblVideos (ID, VideoName) VALUES (2, 'Bowling.3gp');
INSERT INTO tblVideos (ID, VideoName) VALUES (3, 'Car.3gp');
INSERT INTO tblImageVideoLink (LinkID, ImageID, VideoID) VALUES (1, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO tblImageVideoLink (LinkID, ImageID, VideoID) VALUES (2, 3, 3);
INSERT INTO tblPages (ID, PageName) VALUES (1, 'Misc');
```

I am trying to run this query to get all the images with a certain page, and their related videos:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.ID AS 'Image ID', I.ImageName, V.ID AS 'Video ID', V.VideoName
FROM tblImages I
LEFT JOIN tblImageVideoLink L ON L.VideoID=V.ID
LEFT JOIN tblVideos V ON L.ImageID=I.ID
WHERE I.Page=1;
```

When I test it in [SQLite Administrator](http://sqliteadmin.orbmu2k.de/), I am getting the **desired** result set, which is:
[image]

When I test it in the App (or in [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/doku.php/products/sqlitespy/index)) I am getting a *different* result set:
[image]

I have tried everything I know, including GROUP BY, removing the DISTINCT, different JOIN types, etc.

BTW, SQLiteSpy writes at the bottom: SQLite 3.7.8 while SQLite Administrator writes SQLite 3.5.1. I don't know if it matters.

Please help, and also kindly explain why there's a difference between two SQLite tools...

Comment: Can you explain a bit more verbose what exactly is going wrong and show some more info, per example also the IDs? Oh, and you should read up on SQLite's datatypes, varchar does nothing in SQLite; http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: I've added more data (i.e. IDs) to make it clearer. When I've changed from VARCHAR to TEXT, I am no longer able to insert values into the `TEXT` fields using INSERT commands nor manually using SQLite Administrator. Not only that, but also the data set comes out empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dear friend and DBA helped me spot my issue. Here's the working query to JOIN the two tables and get the data set I wanted:

```
SELECT DISTINCT I.ID AS 'Image ID', I.ImageName, V.ID AS 'Video ID', V.VideoName
FROM tblImages I
LEFT JOIN tblImageVideoLink L ON L.ImageID=I.ID
LEFT JOIN tblVideos V ON L.VideoID=V.ID
WHERE I.Page=1;
```

Thank you all for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in SQLLite Admin is (considering your output) same as 
`SELECT DISTINCT(I.ImageName), V.VideoName`

What you actual seeing in app is (considering your output) same as 
`SELECT DISTINCT(I.ImageName, V.VideoName)`

Try brackets

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(I.ImageName, V.VideoName)` throws an error: SQL Error near "," syntax error.